# Deleting an if condition

Tags: php, vbulletin

I am having trouble into finding the correct `</vb:if>` to to delete for the `<vb:if condition="$show['member']">` condition. Sadly notepad++ couldn't locate the `</vb:if>` delete.My aim here is just to remove that if statement.

Here is the full code

```
<vb:if condition="$show['guest']">

       <div class="guestwarn">
           <a href="javascript://" class="close" onclick="YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('guest_message', 'display', 'none');" title=""></a>
           Hello Guest, if you reading this it means you have not yet registered. Please take a second to Click <a href="register.php">here</a> to register and in a few simple steps, you will be able to enjoy all the features of our fine community. <a href="register.php">Register Now</a>
       </div>
</vb:if>
<vb:if condition="$show['member']">
<div id="pageWrapper"><div class="pageWrap">
        <div id="topBar">
            <div class="loginBox">
    <div id="toplinks" class="toplinks">
            <ul class="isuser">
                <li><a href="login.php?{vb:raw session.sessionurl}do=logout&amp;logouthash={vb:raw bbuserinfo.logouthash}" onclick="return log_out('{vb:rawphrase sure_you_want_to_log_out}')">{vb:rawphrase log_out}</a></li>
                <li><a href="usercp.php{vb:raw session.sessionurl_q}">{vb:rawphrase user_control_panel}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{vb:link member, {vb:raw bbuserinfo}}">{vb:rawphrase your_profile}</a></li>
                <vb:if condition="$notifications_total">
                <li class="popupmenu notifications" id="notifications">
                    <a class="popupctrl" href="usercp.php{vb:raw session.sessionurl_q}">{vb:rawphrase your_notifications}: <span class="notifications-number"><strong>{vb:raw notifications_total}</strong></span></a>
                    <ul class="popupbody popuphover">
                        {vb:raw notifications_menubits}
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <vb:else />
                <li class="popupmenu nonotifications" id="nonotifications">
                    <a class="popupctrl" href="usercp.php{vb:raw session.sessionurl_q}">{vb:rawphrase your_notifications}</a>
                    <ul class="popupbody popuphover">
                        <li>{vb:rawphrase no_new_messages}</li>
                        <vb:if condition="$show['pmmainlink']"><li><a href="private.php{vb:raw session.sessionurl_q}">{vb:rawphrase inbox}</a></li></vb:if>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </vb:if>
                <li class="welcomelink">{vb:rawphrase welcome_x_link_y, {vb:raw bbuserinfo.username}, {vb:link member, {vb:raw bbuserinfo}}}</li>
                <vb:if condition="$vboptions['enablefacebookconnect']">
                    {vb:raw facebook_header}
                </vb:if>
            </ul>
            {vb:raw template_hook.header_userinfo}
            <vb:comment><p>{vb:rawphrase last_visited_x_at_y, {vb:raw pmbox.lastvisitdate}, {vb:raw pmbox.lastvisittime}}</p></vb:comment>      
    </div>
    <vb:else />
        <div class="loginLeft">
                <!-- login form -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js?v={vb:raw vboptions.simpleversion}"></script>
                <form id="navbar_loginform" action="login.php?{vb:raw session.sessionurl}do=login" method="post" onsubmit="md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, {vb:raw show.nopasswordempty})">

                <ul>
                    <li><div class="userBoxInput"><input type="text" class="loginInput<vb:if condition="!$username"> default-value</vb:if>" name="vb_login_username" id="navbar_username" size="10" accesskey="u" tabindex="101" value="<vb:if condition="$username">{vb:raw username}<vb:else />{vb:rawphrase username}</vb:if>" /></div></li>
                    <li><div class="passBoxInput"><input type="password" class="loginInput" tabindex="102" name="vb_login_password" id="navbar_password" size="10" />
                    <input type="text" class="loginInput default-value" tabindex="102" name="vb_login_password_hint" id="navbar_password_hint" size="10" value="{vb:rawphrase password}" style="display:none;" /></div></li>
                    <li class="rememberMe"><label for="cb_cookieuser_navbar"><input type="checkbox" name="cookieuser" value="1" id="cb_cookieuser_navbar" class="cb_cookieuser_navbar" accesskey="c" tabindex="103" /> {vb:rawphrase remember_me}</label></li>
                    <li class="loginButton"><input type="image" src="{vb:stylevar imgdir_themedir}/loginButton.png" tabindex="104" value="{vb:rawphrase log_in}" title="{vb:rawphrase enter_username_to_login_or_register}" accesskey="s" /></li>
                </ul>

                <input type="hidden" name="s" value="{vb:raw session.sessionhash}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="{vb:raw bbuserinfo.securitytoken}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="do" value="login" />
                <input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password" />
                <input type="hidden" name="vb_login_md5password_utf" />
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password_hint', "display", "inline");
            YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password', "display", "none");
            vB_XHTML_Ready.subscribe(function()
            {
            //
                YAHOO.util.Event.on('navbar_username', "focus", navbar_username_focus);
                YAHOO.util.Event.on('navbar_username', "blur", navbar_username_blur);
                YAHOO.util.Event.on('navbar_password_hint', "focus", navbar_password_hint);
                YAHOO.util.Event.on('navbar_password', "blur", navbar_password);
            });

            function navbar_username_focus(e)
            {
            //
                var textbox = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(e);
                if (textbox.value == '<vb:if condition="$username">{vb:raw username}<vb:else />{vb:rawphrase username}</vb:if>')
                {
                //
                    textbox.value='';
                    textbox.style.color='{vb:stylevar input_color}';
                }
            }

            function navbar_username_blur(e)
            {
            //
                var textbox = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(e);
                if (textbox.value == '')
                {
                //
                    textbox.value='<vb:if condition="$username">{vb:raw username}<vb:else />{vb:rawphrase username}</vb:if>';
                    textbox.style.color='{vb:stylevar shade_color}';
                }
            }

            function navbar_password_hint(e)
            {
            //
                var textbox = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(e);

                YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password_hint', "display", "none");
                YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password', "display", "inline");
                YAHOO.util.Dom.get('navbar_password').focus();
            }

            function navbar_password(e)
            {
            //
                var textbox = YAHOO.util.Event.getTarget(e);

                if (textbox.value == '')
                {
                    YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password_hint', "display", "inline");
                    YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle('navbar_password', "display", "none");
                }
            }
            </script>
                <!-- / login form -->
        </div>
                <vb:if condition="$vboptions['enablefacebookconnect']">
                <div class="loginLeft">
                <ul>
                    {vb:raw facebook_header}
                </ul>
                </div>
                </vb:if>
    </vb:if>

            </div>

<vb:if condition="$vbulletin->options['display_social_icons']==1">
            <div class="socialBox">
                <vb:if condition="$vbulletin->options['facebook_account']"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/OMFGStreams" target="_blank"><img src="{vb:stylevar imgdir_themedir}/iconFacebook.png" alt="Follow us on Facebook" /></a></vb:if>
                <vb:if condition="$vbulletin->options['twitter_account']"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/Plus1HD" target="_blank"><img src="{vb:stylevar imgdir_themedir}/iconTwitter.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter" /></a></vb:if>
                <vb:if condition="$vbulletin->options['linkedin_account']"><a href=" {vb:raw linkedin_account}"><img src="{vb:stylevar imgdir_themedir}/iconLinkedin.png" alt="Linked In" /></a></vb:if>
                <vb:if condition="$vbulletin->options['flickr_account']"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/{vb:raw flickr_account}"><img src="{vb:stylevar imgdir_themedir}/iconFlickr.png" alt="Flickr" /></a></vb:if>
                <vb:if condition="$vbulletin->options['youtube_account']"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/{vb:raw youtube_account}" target="_blank"><img src="{vb:stylevar imgdir_themedir}/iconYoutube.png" alt="Watch us on YouTube" /></a></vb:if>
                <vb:if condition="$vbulletin->options['myspace_account']"><a href="http://www.myspace.com/{vb:raw myspace_account}"><img src="{vb:stylevar imgdir_themedir}/iconMyspace.png" alt="My Space" /></a></vb:if>
                <vb:if condition="$vbulletin->options['blogger_account']"><a href="{vb:raw blogger_account}"><img src="{vb:stylevar imgdir_themedir}/iconBlogger.png" alt="Blogger" /></a></vb:if>
            </div>  
</vb:if>


        </div>
<div class="above_body"> <!-- closing tag is in template navbar -->
<div id="header" class="floatcontainer doc_header">
    <div id="headerBox">
    <vb:if condition="$stylevar['titleimage']"><a name="top" href="{vb:link forumhome}" id="logo"><img src="{vb:stylevar titleimage}" alt="{vb:rawphrase x_powered_by_vbulletin, {vb:raw vboptions.bbtitle}}" /></a></vb:if>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Notepad++ couldn't locate the closing IF automatically because there are some <divs> that are closed in the wrong order. Here is the algorithm to delete a (properly nested/closed) IF condition: count the number of nested `<vb:if ...>` after the `<vb:if condition="$show['member']">`. Every time you reach a `</vb:if>` subtract 1 from your count. When your count is -1 delete all the code between `<vb:if condition="$show['member']">` and the current `</vb:if>`

Comment: @Karoly Horvath i need to delete `<vb:if condition="$show['member']">` but i can't figure which `</vb:if>` has to be deleted

Comment: they come in pairs. they can be nested. conceptually it doesn't differ from figuring out which parenthesis is paired with which one. (surely (you can) do that).

Comment: @Ma3x...i need to count the number of nested `<vb:if ...>`  until i reach the first `</vb:if>` or count till end of file

Comment: @user2650277: You need to count the number of nested `<vb:if ...>` until you reach the `</vb:if>` where your count is exactly -1 (remember at every `</vb:if>` subtract 1 from the count). If the code is valid then you should find it before the end of file. Once you do, delete all the code in between and see if the new code makes sense (if it's valid).

Comment: @Ma3x i don't need to actually delete code between the `<vb:if condition="$show['member']">` and its corresponding `</vb:if>`.All i need is to find that corresponding `</vb:if>` so that i can remove that damn if condition.If you could post the code with the `<vb:if condition="$show['member']">` and its corresponding `</vb:if>` remove would save me some great amount of time

Comment: @user2650277: removing the code or just the opening and ending IFs follows exactly the same logic. You need to find the right closing IF. I gave you the algorithm, now if you would just use it, you would save _me_ some great amount of time :)

Comment: i am doing what you said but i am not reaching -1 stopping at zero